# addUIInterruptionMonitor() not working on device running iOS 14.0.1

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, ios14, xcuitest

Since upgrading my device (iPhone 11) to iOS 14.0.1, I have found addUIInterruptionMonitor() to not be triggered at all. It was working before on iOS 13.4.1, which was the last version I had installed.

My code:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "App Would Like to Send You Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in
    if alert.buttons["Allow"].exists {
        alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
        return true
    }
    return false
}

XCUIApplication().tap()  // interacting with the app to trigger the interruption monitor
```

Nothing in my code has changed since upgrading - the only thing that has changed is the iOS version installed. Has anyone else encountered similar?

Comment: Anyone has fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working with this code:

```
XCUIApplication.otherElements.firstMatch.swipeLeft()
```

or

```
app.otherElements.firstMatch.swipeLeft()
```

The solution was to use the `otherElements.firstMatch`. Somehow there where only `otherElements` inside the `XCUIApplication` view hierarchy. You can use `tap`-event or the `swipe`-event. I find the `swipe`-event least destructive for the UITest state.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by just sleep the execution 10s.

```
Darwin.sleep(10)
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "App Would Like to Send You Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in
    if alert.buttons["Allow"].exists {
        alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
        return true
    }
    return false
}

XCUIApplication().tap()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you put the interruption monitor in your setUp() function:

```
override func setUp() {
 addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "App Would Like to Send You Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in
     if alert.buttons["Allow"].exists {
         alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
         return true
     }
     return false
 }
}
```

Second - if adding a sleep resolves your issue to me this means that this isn't a problem with the iOS version but the behaviour of your application on this iOS version. I've had a similar problem where the dummy tap that should trigger the UIInterruptionMonitor was actually being executed before the prompt has appeared which lead to not handling the prompt. You could create a small expectation that waits for either your app loading(by checking some element is present) or until the prompt has appeared and then perform the dummy tap.